# How do I stop my script from looping

Tags: windows, powershell, server, active-directory

I am running the attached script against my AD. I only need the script to return each AD account once, but it seems to be running in an infinite loop.

How do I stop this?

Thanks

```
Search-ADAccount -AccountExpired | foreach { get-aduser -Filter 'description -like "*leaver*"' }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem lies within too complex foreach loop and poorly filtered query. Let's take a closer look:

```
Search-ADAccount -AccountExpired | foreach { # 1
    get-aduser -Filter 'description -like "*leaver*"' # 2
}
```

In the part #1, you'll get a list of all user and computer accounts that have expired. So far so good.

In the part #2, you pass one by one each expired account on the pipeline. Now, for *every* expired account found, you search AD for *all* user accounts that have description containing string `leaver`. This makes no sense at all. (What's even worse, searching for a substring requires reading every object's description.)

As a concrete example, having 100 expired accounts and 1000 AD user accounts, the loop is doing 100*1000 search operations. Oops! No wonder it seems to take ages.

As working alternative, consider something like so (not tested on a real domain, so YMMV),

```
$expiredAccounts = Search-ADAccount -AccountExpired # 1
$expiredAccounts| foreach { # 2
    get-aduser -Filter {samaccountname -eq $_.samaccountname -and description -like "*leaver*"} # 3
}
```

In the part #1, save the expired accounts in a variable. This makes no difference, but if these are needed later on, no need to re-search the AD.

In the part #2, pipe results onward. Nothing important here.

In the part #3, search the AD with much more effective filtering.

Comment: You are a life saver! Thank you! Works perfectly!